# Any Character for ex. 'a' should enter only one time in asp.net textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, events

I have one textbox. onkeypress event it is calling checkPostalCode funtion.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPostalCode" runat="server" CssClass="textbox-width form-control" onkeypress="return checkPostalCode(event,this)" TabIndex="14" MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function checkPostalCode(e, t) {
  if (window.event) {
    var charCode = window.event.keyCode;
  } else if (e) {
    var charCode = e.which;
  }
  //Some other Funtionalities
}
```

Is there any method that we can enter any character or number only one time on textbox?

Comment: you mean he shouldnt be able to type duplicate characters or numbers ?

Comment: Yes @KunalMukherjee

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the existing value inside the textbox using

```
var value=document.getElementById("#txtPostalCode");
```

check for index of the new char code

```
var index=value.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(charcode));
if(index="-1")
{
 //character not present
}
else
{
 //character already present
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The way I would do that is construct a frequency array of the characters then check if any frequency value is greater than 1, if yes then return true else return false.**

---

**Example:**

```js
function checkPostalCode(event, t) {
  if (!event.currentTarget.value && event.keyCode !== 13) {
    alert(`Please enter something!`);
    return;
  } else {
    const input = event.currentTarget.value;

    const inputArray = [...input];

    // Construct frequency array of the input
    const frequencyinputArray = inputArray.reduce((prev, curr) => {
      prev[curr] = prev[curr] ? prev[curr] + 1 : 1;
      return prev;
    }, {});

    // Check in the frequency array if any count is greater than 1
    const doesContainRepeatedCharacters = Object.values(frequencyinputArray).some(x => x > 1);
    console.log(doesContainRepeatedCharacters);
    return doesContainRepeatedCharacters;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="txtPostalCode" class="textbox-width form-control" onkeyup="checkPostalCode(event,this)" />
```